# Reversing a fraudulent Microsoft Family account connection

Tags: microsoft-account

My friend just put this request to me. I spent a 1/2 hour looking for the answer myself, but there doesn't appear to be an easily located fraud reporting process. Does anyone know how to remove a Microsoft Account from a family, when the person who attached it is not the parent, fraudulently so?

> My 14 year old son comes in complaining that he cannot use Google
>   Chrome on his computer (the only Windows box in the house). Intrigued,
>   I try to run Chrome, to be confronted by a dialog saying that he has
>   to ask permission from an adult, and that the computer will send an
>   email on his behalf to his parents.
>
> This is intriguing because as far as I know the computer has no idea
>   who his parents are. We've never told it. Clicking the “email” button
>   has no apparent effect.
>
> [Later] it becomes apparent that someone has hacking his Microsoft
>   online account. Someone... has managed to get my son's account
>   assigned to him as the parent. In other words, according to Microsoft,
>   I am not my son's father... [and] my wife's credit card is listed as
>   the default payment option on this new “family”.
>
> How do I get that reversed?

He goes on to note that Microsoft Support recommended such things as hacking the perpetrator of the fraud in turn, to get enough personal information to log in... which also sounded pretty odd to me. Is there a fraud reporting workflow somewhere?

Comment: Well, Microsoft knows your friend's son is a minor (and a lot more). It's reasonable - if you buy into that crap - for Microsoft to treat his account as a limited one.Whether he *told* the computer or not is irrelevant, online account aren't tied to a specific PC. Something could have happened anywhere else where the account was used, a XBox or even his phone. That the credit card associated with it is known makes me think he may have clicked something and doesn't remember and that it isn't really a fraud (...)

Comment: (...) What would be the purpose of said "fraud"? What would be the gain for the supposed "third-party"? None. That party wouldn't be able to use anything billed to that CC, the only beneficiary being your friend's son. It makes no sense, at all. Maybe a prank or a mistake. If it's a fraud it's a pretty stupid one.

Comment: If there's a bit of malware on the computer, then the fraud would be to use the malware to request purchases in the child's name, and then approve them using the fraudulently connected account with the mother's card already attached. 

It's convoluted, but so is most Bayesian-resistant online fraud these days. 


What I'm looking for is whether Microsoft has a process for separating an account from Microsoft Family Safety when the connection was made due to possible  fraud.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the father in this situation.

The ultimate answer to solving the problem, as far as we have figured it out, was:

- create a local Windows login, so my son can use his computer again. The local login is NOT tied to a Microsoft.com account. So my son can now run Chrome, and anything else he wants. You do this by going into Settings  > Accounts  > Family & other people > Add someone else to this PC. At the bottom of the page, select I don’t have this person’s sign-in information, and at the bottom of the next page, select Add a user without a Microsoft account. Make the new user an administrator. Copy the home directory of the old account to the new account, so that no files are lost. Then log out of the old account and delete it.
- have my wife's credit card cancelled so the "owner" of the fraudulent family account can't charge anything to it.

What we were not able to do was have my son's Microsoft.com account removed from the fictional family created by the hacker (note that he was listed as a child member of a family where the adult was someone we do not know, and there were no other members of the family. Just my son, and a random dude's email account).

Microsoft did, in fact, recommend that we attempt to get the random dude's Microsoft password reset by requesting a password reset through the Microsoft web page, and then attempting to guess his personal information in order to "prove" to Microsoft that I was him. This, needless to say, was never going to work, and I question its legality in any case.

We were not able to identify any means to report fraud to Microsoft.